# Parition an Array

Tags: java

Given a array of integers find the index which partitions the array to two with high numbers and low numbers. For example [5, -1, 3, 8,6] the index 3 will partition the array to [5,-1,3] and [8,6] all the numbers in the second partition are greater than first. The solution has to work in O(n).  Please suggest if this is correct and achieves O(n) complexity.

```
private int calculateWinters(int[] a) {
        System.out.println(partition(a, 0, a.length - 1));
        return partition(a, 0, a.length - 1);

    }

    int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {
        int pivot = arr[low];
        int i = low; // index of smaller element
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = low; j <= high; j++) {
            // If current element is smaller than or
            // equal to pivot

            if (arr[j] <= pivot) {

                i++;
                i += count;
                count = 0;

            } else {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = pivot;
                pivot = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: It does achieve O(n) complexity but it doesn't seem to do what you want. In your `else` part you are swapping entries in the array - that is not in the description of the requirement.

Comment: Well.. *is it* correct? What are you asking about if you cannot even verify your own requirements? This is the *very least* you should be able to do coming here with a problem.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Can you suggest a better solution, without swapping as I just wan the index.

Comment: @shivamoberoi - You seem to have copied a `partition` method from some kind of `quicksort` code. This is not a good idea - you should try to understand the problem and work on a solution of your own. Think carefully about what is needed and how a stupid computer could do it, then write your code.

Comment: If the goal is to split the array between high numbers and low numbers and the array is already sorted then why can't you just pick _any_ index? If it is sorted then it doesn't matter where you split it - one will always contain smaller numbers than the other.

Comment: @csm_dev Not necessary array will always be sorted, we have to find a minimum index where we can get the subarray of all number greater than the numbers on the right

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Winters w = new Winters();
        int[] a = { 5, 4, 2, 10, 8, 78, 21, 2, 33 };
        w.calculateWinters(a);

    }

    private int calculateWinters(int[] a) {
        System.out.println(partition(a, 0, a.length - 1));
        return partition(a, 0, a.length - 1);

    }

    int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {
        int pivot = arr[low];
        int i = low; // index of smaller element
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        while (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            list1.add(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }

        for (int k = i; k <= arr.length - 1; k++) {
            list.add(arr[k]);
            if (list1.size() > 1 && arr[k] < Collections.max(list1)) {
                list1.addAll(list);
                i = i + (k - i) + 1;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: This is the best solution, I can think of with O(n).

Comment: Then you should explain that and show how this code is different from the code in the question. Don't just copy paste code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int calculateWinters(int[] a) {
            System.out.println(partition(a, 0, a.length - 1));
            return partition(a, 0, a.length - 1);

        }

        int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {
            int pivot = arr[low];
            int i = low; // index of smaller element
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();// This is the list which will add all the numbers of an array which are smaller than pivot
            List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();//This will contain all the number which are greater than the pivot
            while (arr[i] <= pivot) {
                list1.add(arr[i]);
                i++;
            }

            for (int k = i; k <= arr.length - 1; k++) {
                list.add(arr[k]);//adding all numbers greater than the pivot.
//if we find any number smaller than the  than the max of already encountered numbers, we will move the index(i) to the current pointer.
                if (list1.size() > 1 && arr[k] < Collections.max(list1)) {
                    list1.addAll(list);
                    i = i + (k - i) + 1;
                }
            }

            return i;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer?